# shell script to get the o/p in order

Tags: shell

I have file o/p like

```
1.2.3.4
==========
ok
1.2.3.4
===========
not good 
1.2.3.5
========
good
1.2.3.5
==========
bad

1.2.3.7
========
bad 

1.2.3.6
=========
good

1.2.3.7
=========
very good 

I need o/p like 
1.2.3.4
ok
not good 

1.2.3.5
good
bad

1.2.3.7
good
very good 

1.2.3.6
good
```

any help appericated 
tried ith the awk not getting exact o/p

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Do you mean: For all digit.digit.digit.digit lines I want to see all the qualifications? In that case your example `1.2.3.7` should show bad/very good. (Please explain what is o.p.)

Comment: yes where the digit are the IP address it keep changing .

Answer (score 0):

**cat data.txt**

```
1.2.3.4
==========
ok
1.2.3.4
===========
not good 
1.2.3.5
========
good
1.2.3.5
==========
bad

1.2.3.7
========
bad 

1.2.3.6
=========
good

1.2.3.7
=========
very good
```

**| sed s/=//g**

```
1.2.3.4

ok
1.2.3.4

not good 
1.2.3.5

good
1.2.3.5

bad

1.2.3.7

bad 

1.2.3.6

good

1.2.3.7

very good
```

**| grep -v '^$'**

```
1.2.3.4
ok
1.2.3.4
not good 
1.2.3.5
good
1.2.3.5
bad
1.2.3.7
bad 
1.2.3.6
good
1.2.3.7
very good
```

**| paste - - | sort**

```
1.2.3.4 not good 
1.2.3.4 ok
1.2.3.5 bad
1.2.3.5 good
1.2.3.6 good
1.2.3.7 bad 
1.2.3.7 very good
```

**| tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/^/|/'**

```
|1.2.3.4    not good |1.2.3.4   ok|1.2.3.5  bad|1.2.3.5 good|1.2.3.6    good|1.2.3.7    bad |1.2.3.7    very good |
```

**| sed 's/|1.2.3.4//g2' | sed 's/|1.2.3.5//g2' | sed 's/|1.2.3.7//g2'**

```
|1.2.3.4    not good    ok|1.2.3.5  bad good|1.2.3.6    good|1.2.3.7    bad     very good |
```

**| tr '|' '\n' | sed -e 's/$/\n/' | tr '\t' '\n' | tail -n +3 | sed '$ d'**

```
1.2.3.4
not good 
ok

1.2.3.5
bad
good

1.2.3.6
good

1.2.3.7
bad 
very good
```

---

**final:**

```
cat data.txt | sed s/=//g | grep -v '^$' | paste - - | sort | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/^/|/' | sed 's/|1.2.3.4//g2' | sed 's/|1.2.3.5//g2' | sed 's/|1.2.3.7//g2' | tr '|' '\n' | sed -e 's/$/\n/' | tr '\t' '\n' | tail -n +3 | sed '$ d'
```